# Trying to sort a pivot table by aggfunc count

Tags: python, python-3.x, pivot-table, counter, aggregate-functions

```
idex = ['Tipo_Propiedad','Localidad','Lugar']
capital_pivot = capital.pivot_table(index=idex, aggfunc={'PrecioU$dM2': 
('mean','std'),'Lugar':'count'})
capital_pivot.sort_values('count', ascending=False)
```

I'm trying to sort a pivot table by the aggfunc count. Have tried different ways but seem to be missing something

Comment: Why do you think there's something missing? What's the output you're getting and what was your expected output?

Comment: I want to see the pivot table sorted by the count column (count being an aggfunc of column 'Lugar'). When i use 'count' i get "# Check for duplicates". When i use count i get "name 'count' is not defined"